# Function name is not decorated

Tags: dllexport, name-mangling

I am building a DLL which is having static reference to a library (.lib). Both the DLL and .lib has a function with same name but with different signature. I want to export the function written for the DLL. I am using .def file for exporting the function. 
However, When I use dumpbin to export the function from the DLL, I dont see the decorated name for this function (having two function of the same name), for all other function I do see decorated name.

Function in A.cpp (DllName - ADLL)

```
uint __stdcall func(MSIHANDLE hHandle)
uint __stdcall func1(MSIHANDLE hHandle)
```

Function in .lib (B.lib) which is statically referenced in ADLL

```
DWORD WINAPI  func(__in const bool input);
```

Format of def (ADLL.def) file :

```
LIBRARY  "ADLL"
EXPORTS
   func
   func1
```

Snippet from .vcxProj

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
   <Link>
     <ModuleDefinitionFile>ADLL.def</ModuleDefinitionFile>
   </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Output from Dumpbin /Exports

```
ordinal    hint      RVA         name
2             0     00035560    func = func
1             1     00001370    func1 = @ILT+875(?func1@@YAIK@Z)
```

I am not able to understand why the function "func" doesn't have a decorated name like func1?

Comment: Your question is too unspecific. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: now I can't understand why you are telling about the same name but different signature. `func` and `func1` have different names and the same signature. It is exactly the opposite.

Comment: @aparpara - I am talking about the function in A.cpp and function in .lib, both having the same name (func) but different signature. The second function func1 is an another function which is showing the correct decorated name.

Comment: Which *func* do you think the exported undecorated *func* is? What's your *CPU* architecture? You also need to provide the header files containing the functions prototypes, maybe you can find something there (`extern "C"` or smth similar).